# Filtering and replacing the value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror, pandas-loc

I am trying to filter the rows of a DataFrame according to the below conditions and want to replace the values by a new value of a column. The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'
```

The picture of df is in link.

[image: dataset**]

```
data1=data.loc[data['dob_years']==0] & data.loc[data['income_type']=='retiree']
replace value of dob_years==0 by 60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
data1 = data[(data['dob_years']==0) & (data['income_type']=='retiree')]
```

And then:

```py
data1['dob_years'].replace(0,60, inplace=True)
```